# How to call .increaseAllowance() from another token

Tags: solidity, remix, transfer, erc-20-approve, allowance

I'm deploying a contract that is the owner of a token. In that contract i want to say that the token increaseAllowance to msg.sender and the amount that msg.send have putted in arguments of the function.
Example:

function setAllowance(uint256 _amount){
token.increaseAllowance(address(msg.sender),_amount)
}

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Should probably look something like this:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

interface ISPCT is IERC20 {
    function increaseAllowance(address, uint256) external virtual returns (bool);
}


contract canAllow {
    ISPCT public spctContract;
    address public SPCTaddress;

    constructor(address _SPCT) {
        SPCTaddress = _SPCT;
        spctContract = ISPCT(SPCTaddress);
    }

    function setAllowance(uint256 _amount){
        bool increasedAllowance = spctContract.increaseAllowance(msg.sender, _amount);
        require(increasedAllowance, "no_allowance");
    }
}
```